# Crear un menú desplegable segun un array almacenado en BD

Tags: php, html5, css3

les resumo brevemente lo que quiero hacer. Tengo un formulario de registro de usuarios donde el usuario ademas de ingresar los datos clásicos, ingresa el tipo de perfil. Eso lo hago a traves de un select multiple. Ahora bien el usuario puede ser de tipo 1, 2, 3 o 4 o puede ser una combinacion de ellas. Por ejemplo puede ser 1 y 2, 1 y 3 por ejemplo o hasta puede ser todos al mismo tiempo. Esa seleccion del select multiple logre almacenarla con la estructura siguiente:
`<ul><li>1</li><li>2</li><li>3</li><li>4</li></ul>`
Ahora bien, resulta que cuando ingresa hago lo siguiente

```
$idUsuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

$sql = "SELECT id, nombre, usuario, clase FROM usuarios WHERE id = '$idUsuario'";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_assoc();
```

ese campo "clase" es donde viene esa cadena que explique.
Lo que ocurre es que de acuerdo a esos tipo de perfil, el usuario accederá a opciones especiales para ese tipo de perfiles entonces se me ocurrio hacer lo siguiente:

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li class="button"><a href="../perfil/perfilusuario.php">Mi Perfil</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <?php if((intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '',($_SESSION['clase']))))==1) { ?>
                          <li class="button"><a href="#">Mi menu para Tipo 1</a></li>
                        <?php } ?>
```

con lo que quiero extraer de esa cadena, los numeros de la clase de usuario. Pero al ejecutarlo me arroja el siguiente error:

```
Notice: Undefined index: clase in (la linea donde esta el preg_replace)
```

Desde ya les agradezco alguna sugerencia...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sugerencia que te hago es:

Primero, sacas el query, tienes los datos. Ahora dices, según el tipo de string que podría definirse como "un roll de usuario", si el roll es 1, muestra ese menú, si el roll es 2, muestra aquel otro.

Podrías simplemente hacer una condición que diga

`Guardas tus rolles como cadena de texto "1-2-3-4" en la base de datos y al extraerlos los guardas en la variable rolls para empezar la logica con ella.
.
rolls = class;  <-> rolls = '1-2';
rolls = explode('-',rolls); 
.
El resultado sería en este caso
.
rolls[0] = 1;
rolls[1] = 2;
.
Aqui genera un array con todos los numeros que serian los rolles.
Haces una condición que diga, si tiene 1 roll que checkee cual es y lo muestre,
si tiene 2 roles, que en cada vuelta chequee y pinte los que tenga. En este caso no mostraria el menú 3 ya que en cada vuelta va viendo cuales tiene y si no existe en el array de roles no lo pone
.
Si hacemos un count del array "rolls" nos dirá el nº de elementos o rolles presentes. 1,2,3,4..
.
Usamos "count(rolls)" en una condicion
.
 // SI TIENE 1 ROLL
  if (count(rolls) = 1)
    for(i = 0; i < count(rolls); i++)
      if(rolls[i] == '1')
        <li class="button"><a href="#">Mi menu para Tipo 1</a></li>
      elseif(rolls[i] == '2')
        <li class="button"><a href="#">Mi menu para Tipo 2</a></li>
      endif
 // SI TIENE 2 ROLES
  elseif (count(rolls) = 2)
    for(i = 0; i < count(rolls); i++)
      if(rolls[i] == '1'])
        <li class="button"><a href="#">Mi menu para Tipo 1</a></li>
      elseif(rolls[i] == '2')
        <li class="button"><a href="#">Mi menu para Tipo 2</a></li>
      elseif(rolls[i] == '3')
        <li class="button"><a href="#">Mi menu para Tipo 3</a></li>
      endif
    endfor
  endif
 // SI TIENE 3 ROLES ...
  elseif (count(rolls) = 3)`

Digamos, tu archivo como tal va a ser mas largo, cierto pero si piensas como se ejcuta el código, no va a ser mas largo en la carga del mismo. Ya que según la condición solo se ejecutará el cachito de menu que quieres poner y el resto no se lee ya que no entra por esa condición.

Por otro lado la idea de separar los que tienen 1,2,3 roles es para diferenciar la lógica por niveles ya que igual, cuantos mas roles mas nivel tendrá y asi localizar y separar lo que le vas a mostrar de forma mas restrictiva y controlada.
No vaya a ser que a un usuario roll 1 le muestres una barra de menú de administración roll 3. xD

Comment: simplemente excelente !!!